# woocommerce search for sql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using SQL queries to load woocmmerce products.

My code is as below

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_type, (select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key='_sku' and post_id=ID ) as sku 
FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta 
where post_type='product' and post_status='publish' and post_id=ID 
group by ID
```

In this code, I want to search with SKU, postid, post title, so I wrote the code below code, which is not working properly.

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_type, (select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key='_sku' and post_id=ID ) as sku  
FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta   
where post_type='product' and post_status='publish' 
  **AND ( post_title LIKE 'WS1006%'  OR sku LIKE 'WS1006%'  OR ID LIKE 'WS1006%' ) 
group by ID**
```

Comment: This query make code work very slower

It take too much time to complete action

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below query.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sku' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as sku
    FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID)                 
    WHERE p.post_type in('product') AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND post_id=ID
    GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: but i am not able to underatand why you used max

Comment: the MAX() of the values returned by the CASE expression. 
In character columns MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use alias on where condition to use alias as condition you need to use that in having clause.

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_type, (select meta_value from wp_postmeta where
 meta_key='_sku' and post_id=ID ) as sku FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta where 
 post_type='product' and post_status='publish' group by ID Having ( post_title 
 LIKE '%WS1006%' OR sku LIKE '%WS1006%' OR ID LIKE '%WS1006%' )
```

This will work.